# В чём разница между DI, DI-контейнером и сервис-локатором?

Tags: ооп

Не совсем понимаю чем конкретно отличаются эти понятия, был бы благодарен за разъяснение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DI (Dependency Injection) - внедрение зависимостей.** Если класс или метод зависит от другого класса, то эту зависимость он получает откуда-то извне, используя аргументы конструктора или метода (пример на C#):

```
public class A
{
   private IClassDependency _foo;
   
   // внедрение через конструктор
   public A(IClassDependency foo)
   {
       _foo = foo;
   }
   
   // внедрение через метод
   public void Method(IMethodDependency bar)
   {
       bar.DoSmth();
   }
}
```

сам класс не отвечает за создание объектов.

**DI-контейнер - контейнер разрешения зависимостей.** Используется для определения того, какой конкретный тип скрывается за абстракцией зависимости. Зарегистрировав в контейнере конкретный класс `ConcreteClassDependency` как разрешение `IClassDependency`, всякий раз. когда нам понадобится `IСlassDependency` контейнер создаст экземпляр `ConcreteClassDependency`, автоматически разрешив зависимости создаваемого класса.

**Сервис-локатор** - это использование контейнера разрешения зависимостей внутри классов для получения их зависимостей:

```
public class A
{
   private IClassDependency _foo;
   
   // внедрения нет. Зависимость от IClassDependency разрешается через контейнер
   public A()
   {
       _foo = Container.Get<IClassDependency>;
   }
}
```

Сервис-локатор приводит к скрытию зависимостей класса. Так класс `A` не показывает клиентам, что зависит от `IClassDependency`. Более того, все или почти все классы начинают зависеть от контейнера. Поэтому часто сервис-локатор называют антипаттерном проектирования. Чтобы DI-контейнер не стал сервис-локатором его использование следует ограничить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а не могли бы Вы немного пояснить последнюю фразу: "Чтобы DI-контейнер не стал сервис-локатором его использование следует ограничить."

Comment: @S.H., Имел в виду, что использовать контейнер следует только там, где происходит конфигурирование запускаемой задачи. Это может быть точка входа в программу, начало обработки нового запроса к сервису и т.д. Использование контейнера после завершения конфигурирования задачи приведёт к сервис-локатору